# android dialog needs to be tapped twice. Why?

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I am running into a weird bug. Basically I have a edittext box that triggered a time control as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCourseTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editCourseDate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:ems="10"/>
```

And here is the code

```
    private void setupUserTimeListener()
{
    editTextCourseTime.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    editTextCourseTime.setOnClickListener(this);

    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    timePickerDlg = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            editTextCourseTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);
    timePickerDlg.setTitle("Select Time");
}
```

the call

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view == editTextCourseTime)
    {
        timePickerDlg.show();
    }
 etc...
```

The code works, but it has an annoyance I need to tap the box twice to get the timepickerdiadlg to show up.

Does anyone know why?

I copy this code from another thread here, but I can't figure out the "double" tap bug.

thx!

Comment: Change to below in onclick().....`if(view.getId()==R.id.editCourseTime){timePickerDlg.show();}`

Comment: never mind the issue is that I need to create a listener to the focus not to the click.

Comment: You meant listener to the click and not focus right?